# Error when converting python list to numpy

Tags: python, numpy

The following code:

```
class1 = genfromtxt('example.csv',, delimiter=',')
#rest of the classes are loaded in the same way  



timejoin = []
classlist = []
class_list=[class1,class2,class3,class4,class5,class6,class7]

print class1.shape

print len(timejoin)

classcounter = 0
for class_i in class_list:
    classcounter = classcounter + 1
    odd = class_i[1::2]
    even = class_i[1::2]
    oddandeven = np.concatenate((odd, even), axis=1)
    print oddandeven.shape
    timejoin.append(oddandeven)
    countervector = np.full((oddandeven.shape[0],1), classcounter)
    print countervector.shape
    classlist.append(countervector)
    break


print len(timejoin)


timejoin1 = np.array(timejoin)
classlist1 = np.array(classlist)
print timejoin1.shape
print classlist1.shape
```

Has the following prints output:

```
(52L, 350L)
0
(26L, 700L)
(26L, 1L)
1
(1L, 26L, 700L)
(1L, 26L, 1L)
```

when break is removed, the prints produce:

```
(52L, 350L)
0
(26L, 700L)
(26L, 1L)
(22L, 700L)
(22L, 1L)
(15L, 700L)
(15L, 1L)
(25L, 700L)
(25L, 1L)
(21L, 700L)
(21L, 1L)
(27L, 700L)
(27L, 1L)
(26L, 700L)
(26L, 1L)
7
(7L,)
(7L,)
```

The last 2 elements are the list to numpy conversions.
Does anybody knows what is going on? I am not getting the right elements in each list to numpy conversion. The list is suppose to contain the all the class elements.

Comment: which lines in the output are you not happy with?  also, how are you defining `class1`?

Comment: class_i is being loaded from a CSV file. the list is not appending the class elements correctly.

Comment: it's important that you be precise with your wording here.  which list?  it's also not at all clear what "correctly" means, because you haven't stated what your goal is -- what output you want.

Comment: you seem to be unhappy with the last two lines of output, but these lines show that the numpy arrays `timejoin1` and `classlist1` have the same number of elements as the list `timejoin`.

Comment: The problem here is that I am appending numpy arrays to lists and the list are not appending the numpy arrays correctly for some reason. to be clear this is my problem in a simplified way:  7 files of mxn when appended to a list produce 7 elements, no the 7*(mxn) elements of the 7 files

Comment: are you saying you're not happy with `class_list` having length 7?  please refer to your code when describing what you want to happen.

Comment: I want the following numpy arrays: (26L, 700L)
(26L, 1L)
(22L, 700L)
(22L, 1L)
(15L, 700L)
(15L, 1L)
(25L, 700L)
(25L, 1L)
(21L, 700L)
(21L, 1L)
(27L, 700L)
(27L, 1L)
(26L, 700L)
(26L, 1L) correctly be appended to a list and then convert the list to a numpy array. in the code I am including the resulting list has 7 elements, which are not all the contents of the numpy arrays appended. is this clear now?

Comment: print class1.shape: (52L, 350L) a row from the file has the form:
314.5971045, 314.4822207, 314.3246546, 314.184498.....

Comment: Each row of the list should be a row of a numpy array of class_i, all the rows of all the numpy arrays should be in the list as rows

Comment: Do you really need 7 classes and 20 lines of output to explain your problem? Please, try again with a compact and clean example, stating the expected output and the obtained output. And leaving a closed CSV in the question makes it impossible for anyone to try to replicate your problem. I insist: present a minimal example of what is not working, not a snipet of your source.

Comment: What's the dtype of `classlist1`?  Have you looked at its contents.  Also add labels to the print lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `class_i` you construct:

```
print oddandeven.shape
timejoin.append(oddandeven)
```

and the cooresponding prints are (if I have deduced things correctly)

```
(26L, 700L)
(22L, 700L)
...
```

In other words, `timejoin` is a list of 7 arrays, each with different dimensions.  `np.array(timejoin)` will then be an array with `dtype=object`, where each element is one of those arrays.

If the arrays had matching dimensions, it would construct with a shape like `(7,22,700)`.  But that is impossible in this case.

Have you looked at `timejoin1` itself, not just its shape?  That should have given you a clue.

You also need to clean up the prints.  Put some labels on the lines.  We should be able to read your code and output and easily see what is going on.

If all the arrays in your list have the same number of columns, then `np.vstack` will concatenate  the rows.

```
In [156]: class1=np.empty((26,700))

In [157]: class2=np.empty((22,700))

In [158]: class3=np.empty((10,700))

In [159]: np.vstack([class1,class2,class3]).shape
Out[159]: (58, 700)
# or np.concatenate([class1,class2,class3],axis=0)
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what is going on. the numpy arrays are being appended to the list as objects. Is there a way I can append the numpy arrays as arrays, which are appended by rows? The final timejoin1 array should have  dimensions= (sum(rows of all classes), 700)

Comment: The original question was to append numpy arrays to a list and then convert the list to numpy array.

Comment: It doesn't really matter how you created the list, with `append` or `[...]` or something else.  The issue is, how to convert a list of arrays into one array.  If the array shapes are right, this `vstack` does the job you want.

Comment: I know what is the problem now: The numpy arrays have different sizes, that is the reason why they are being appended as object to the list, and not getting the desired output list to numpy array conversion (in this case use vstack as you said). If all numpy arrays have same size, then they can be correctly appended to a list as arrays and then convert correctly the list to a numpy array